# Can characters be graphed in a histogram in R?

Tags: r, plot

So I have a data frame which I will call R. Looks something like this:

```
        zep  SEX       AGE    BMI
   1     O    F    3.416667 16.00000
   2     O    F    3.833333 14.87937
   3     O    G    3.416667 14.80223
   4     O    F    4.000000 15.09656
   5     N    G    3.666667 16.50000
   6     O    G    4.000000 16.49102
   7     N    G    3.916667 16.02413
```

With this data frame I want to plot multiple histograms comparing different aspects like how gender effects BMI. Like so:

```
 par(mfrow=c(1,3)

boxplot(DF$BMI ~ DF$ZEP)

boxplot(DF$BMI ~ DF$GENDER)

boxplot(DF$BMI ~ ~ DF$AGE)
```

But for some reason the columns are made to be in characters instead of factors.

Now I pose this, is there a way to plot these if they are characters? If not,what can I do?

Also is there a way maybe to change zep and sex into a vector of logical factors? Maybe like in zep if O then true (1) if not then false (0), and the same thing for SEX. If G then true (1) if not then false (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to plot categorical variables for me advanced data analysis class. I can help you out. `beed`*stands for border entry and employment data, don't steal my research plz.*

The code I use to create factors is for example: (I have a column called portname that is dummy variables in a column, to create a column with factor variables (the names) This is how I would make the logical you describe. I've added that code with the larger code chunk below.

```
 beed$portdisc <- as.numeric(beed$portname)
 beed$portdisc[beed$portdisc==0] <- "Columbus Port of Entry"
 beed$portdisc[beed$portdisc==1] <- "Santa Teresa Port of Entry"
 beed$portdisc[beed$portdisc==2] <- "New Mexico All Ports Aggregate"
```

So what I've done here is taken by dataframe `beed` and used the specific column containing my `portname` variables. I add a new column to my dataframe called `beed$portdisc` then using the `[ ]` I define what I want to label as what.

In your case I think this should work (think, but I've tested by using the data you provided).

I have a hard time making the labels come out right with discrete variables. My apologies but this gets you very close.

```
library(ggplot2)

DF$SEX.factor <- as.character(DF$SEX)
DF$SEX.factor[DF$SEX.factor== "G"] <- "0"
DF$SEX.factor[DF$SEX.factor== "F"] <- "1"

DF$SEX.factor <- as.factor(DF$SEX.factor)

bar <- ggplot()
bar <- bar + geom_bar(data = DF$Sex.factor, aes(x=DF$SEX.factor),binwidth = .5)+ xlab("Sex")
bar <- bar + scale_x_discrete(limits = c(0,1,2), breaks= c(0,1,2), labels = c(" ","Male" ,"Female")) 
bar

# DF.BMI5 = cut(DF$BMI,pretty(DF$BMI,5)) # Creates close to 5 integer ranges as factors, actomatically chooses pretty scales.
# This would be good to compair say age and BMI, best with one discreate and one continious variable

p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = SEX.factor, y = BMI))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(width = 0.25, alpha = 0.4)
p <- p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), alpha = .35, color = "blue")
# diamond at mean for each group
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 18, size = 6,
                  colour = "red", alpha = 0.8)
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(limits = c(0,1,2), breaks= c(0,1,2), labels = c(" ","Male" ,"Female")) + xlab("Sex")
p
```

Here is what I got when I ran this code on my own data. I think this is what you're looking to create, I've included the code above. It'll work with anything where x is a discrete variable, just use the at.factor() and set y as type continuous. function/ [image]

If you need any more help just let me know, I like to help out people on here because it helps me hone my R skills. I'm more of an Visual Studio kind of guy, VBA is my friend.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to change a character to a factor, you can always use `as.factor('A')`, for instance.